# General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active when calling a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What I am trying to do is get a product using:

```
$query = "CALL GetAllProducts()";
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
return $statement;
```

and while I am looping through the results like this:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    ....
}
```

I am also querying three different one-to-many relationships in the above while loop. I am getting a list of product variants, product images, and another one....

Here is an example of how I get one of the on-to-many data:

```
$query = "CALL GetProductImages(" . $id . ")";
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
```

The issue I am having is I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000 ]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement: :fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO: :MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I now want to use PDOStatement::fetchAll() to get all the one-to-many data to avoid the above error but I can't find a solution on how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not, its documented in the manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly where, I have been looking for it. I would like to know how do I get the data from it

Comment: **Big Point** There is no security against [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) when you prepare a query that you have already concatentated a value into

Comment: The [PHP Manual page for fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall) found easily and quickly using google

Comment: **Also** `extract($row);` is a horrible and potentially dangerous command as well, and there is almost never a good reason for using it specially not when run in the global scope

Comment: It returns an array of rows. The rows are either returned as arrays (so an array of arrays) or as objects (so an array of objects)

Comment: fetchAll() won't help you here.